# How to set picture url relative in each site collection?

Tags: page-layout

I have a custom pagelayout. Inside this pagelayout I have a picture. this picture is saved in the style library. How can I make the picture url relative?

```
<img id="druppel" src="/Style%20Library/Images/Druppel.jpg" width="97" height="150"/>
```

Comment: src="../Style Library/Images/Druppel.jpg"

Comment: I am using now this and it is working. Is this ok? <img id="Img1" src="<asp:Literal runat='server' Text='<%$SPUrl:~SiteCollection/Style%20Library/Images/Druppel.jpg%>'/>" width="264" height="80"/>

Comment: Yes that way is okay as well. :)